# Jquery load modal box on page load

Tags: jquery, xhtml

I want this modal form to load upon the page loading:

Here's my JQuery so far: (I've tried on document load but didnt work?)

```
$().ready(function() {
  $('#dialog').jqm();
});
```

Comment: Why not just `$(function() { $('#dialog').jqm(); });`? Also, what's `jqm`?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
     $('#dialog').jqm();
});
```